# Where or what is the general formula for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, special-functions, differential-calculus

It is well-known that the power-exponential function $x^x$ and its first few derivatives are often taught in calculus.

Does the general formula for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$ exist somewhere?

What is the general formula for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking if there's some closed form for this rather than just describing it recursively?

Comment: See Louis Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics. Reidel, Dordrecht, 1974, pp. 139–140 and D. H. Lehmer, Numbers associated with Stirling numbers and $x^x$, Rocky Mountain J. Math. 15 (1985), no. 2, 461–479, Number Theory (Winnipeg, Man., 1983).

Comment: Just use the Faà di Bruno formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for $x^x=f(g(x))$ with $f(u)=e^u$ and $g(x)=x\ln x$.

Comment: @IraGessel Merry Christmas! Happy New Year 2023! This night I have derived a general and closed-form formula for the $n$th derivative of the function $x^x$ in terms of the Stirling numbers of the first kind. Later I will compare my result with those you told me. Thank you everybody!

Comment: Related is the MSE question [The $n$'th derivative of $x^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/802256/13130).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Your reference is important. Thank you very much. Wish the New Year 2023 is peaceful, successful, and healthy for youself, your family, and all people around you.

Comment: For $n\in\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$, we have
\begin{equation}
(x^x)^{(n)}=n!x^{x-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} x^{k} \sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell} \Biggl[\sum_{j=0}^{k-\ell}\frac{(-1)^{j}}{(k-\ell-j)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(1+\ln x)^\ell}{\ell!},
\end{equation} where $s(n,k)$ for $n\ge k\ge0$ deonotes the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, you are allowed to answer your own question. Of course, you'll want to do more than simply present an explicit formula. FYI, I have no idea whether what you wrote in the comment is correct, and combinatorics stuff like this is a bit outside of my expertise anyway (meaning don't count on me double-checking it later, pun intended), despite the answer I gave for the MSE question that I cited in a previous comment here a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stirling numbers of the first kind $s(n,k)$ for $n\ge k\ge0$ can be analytically generated by
\begin{equation*}%\label{1st-stirl-gen-funct}
\frac{[\ln(1+t)]^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty s(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!},\quad |t|<1,
\end{equation*}
which can be rearranged as Maclaurin's power series expansion of the power function
\begin{equation}\label{1st-stirl-gen-funct-rewr}
\biggl[\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}\biggr]^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s(n+k,k)}{\binom{n+k}{k}}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}, \quad |t|<1, \quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
Comtet's numbers $b(n,k)$ are generated by
\begin{equation}\label{b(n-k)-gen-eq}
\frac{[(1+t)\ln(1+t)]^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}b(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!},\quad k\ge0.
\end{equation}
For $n\in\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$, we have
\begin{equation}\label{power-exp-deriv-eq}
(x^x)^{(n)}=n!x^{x-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr]\frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{power-exp-deriv-b(n-k)}
(x^x)^{(n)}
=x^{x-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j}\binom{j-n-1}{j} b(n-j,k-j)(\ln x)^{j}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, Taylor's power series expansion around $x=1$ is
\begin{equation}\label{power-exp-taylor-ser}
x^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{q=k}^{n} \frac{s(q,k)}{q!} \binom{k}{n-q}\Biggr](x-1)^n, \quad |x-1|<1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{b(n-k)-ser=1-eq}
x^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{n} b(n,k)\Biggr]\frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}, \quad |x-1|<1.
\end{equation}
These texts are extracted from Theorem 1 of the following paper:

1. Jian Cao, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, *Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$*, Symmetry **15** (2023), no. 2, Article 323, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020323.

Comment: Just now I found the formula $$
[x^{ax}]^{(n)}=x^{ax}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k!}a^k x^{k-n} \sum_{j=0}^{k}{\left(-1\right)^{k-j}\,{{k}\choose{j}}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}{{{{{j}\choose{i}}\sum_{m=0}^{j}{\frac{m!}{(n-i)!}{{j
 }\choose{m}}{\left[n-i \atop m\right]}}}}}\left(\ln x\right)^{k-m}\right)}
$$ on page 8 of the paper "Vladimir V. Kruchinin, Derivation of Bell polynomials of the second kind, arXiv (2011), available online at http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5065".

Comment: In the paper "Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$", it was obtained that
\begin{equation}
\bigl[(1+x)^{t(1+x)}\bigr]^{(n)}
=n!(1+x)^{t(1+x)-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^k(1+x)^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{[\ln(1+x)]^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}
Replacing $1+x$ by $x$ yields
\begin{equation}
\bigl(x^{tx}\bigr)^{(n)}
=n!x^{tx-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^kx^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}.
\end{equation}

Comment: See also Remark 4 in the paper "Wen-Hui Li, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi. Expanding the function $\ln(1+\operatorname{e}^x)$ into power series in terms of the Dirichlet eta function and the Stirling numbers of the second kind. Carpathian Mathematical Publications Vol. 15, (2023), in press; available online at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369476475"

Comment: There is a related paper with this question: Jian Cao, Bai-Ni Guo, Wei-Shih Du, and Feng Qi, *A sufficient and necessary condition for the power-exponential function $(1+\frac1x)^{\alpha x}$ to be a Bernstein function and related $n$th derivatives*, Fractal and Fractional **7** (2023), no. 5, Article 397, 15 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/fractalfract7050397.